# How to stop fragment from popping all the way back to the root fragment ? [Navigation Component]

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, jitpack

I have a side drawer made out of Navigation Component and when I navigate to a fragment with in a fragment and press back it pops the entire stack up to the root fragment. Let me explain.

I navigate from Root fragment to Fragment A (Both of these fragments are defined in the navigation XML file) and then from Fragment A to Fragment B

Root Fragment ---> Fragment A ---> Fragment B.

I have tried defining menuCategory:secondary to my navigation items , use action tag and defining "popupto" and "destination" parameters in the said tag but still no results.

Help would be appreciated.

```
  navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    if(prefsUtils.getFromPrefs(Keys.roleName).equals("PA") ||prefsUtils.getFromPrefs(Keys.roleName).equals("RSM"))
    {
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation);
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_dashboard,R.id.nav_createOrder)
                .setDrawerLayout(binding.drawerLayout)
                .build();
    }

    else if (prefsUtils.getFromPrefs(Keys.roleName).equals("TP"))
    {
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation_tp);
        binding.navView.getMenu().clear();

        binding.navView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer_tp);
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_dashboardTP)
                .setDrawerLayout(binding.drawerLayout)
                .build();
    }

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);

 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    navController.navigateUp();
}
```

Comment: post your nav graph and some code!

Comment: I've added the code for navigation UI and onbackpress

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
findNavController().navigateUp()
```

to avoid popping up entire backstack.

Comment: I used this conde in the onBackPressed but it still pops back to the root fragment.

Answer (score 0):

you can control where your present screen(Fragment B) can go by using

```
 public void onBackPressed(){


 super.onBackPressed();
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragmentA.class));   


}
```

Here startActivity() function write fragment A so that it reverse backs    to the fragment A when back button is clicked in Fragment B.
Write all that above code in Fragment B java class.

Comment: I have around 10 menu items and then around 10 fragments with in those fragments. I don't think it would be efficient to add conditions for so many fragments.